# Simple Unix redirection question: Pass lines in a file as command line arguments to a script

Tags: unix, command-line, command-line-arguments

Ok, my Unix scripting skills are obviously really rusty. All I want to do is have a file with 4 arguments that I want passed to a script as if they came from the command line. But strangely doing this:

```
./myscript.sh < mycmds.txt
```

Doesn't seem to be working the way I expect. Contents of myscript.sh are:

```
cat >> out.txt <<EOF
$1 $2 $3 $4
EOF
```

So if I run myscript.sh from the command line like this: `./myscript.sh test1 test2 test3 test4` everything works great and I see `test1 test2 test3 test4` show up in the out.txt file. But if I put `test1 test2 test3 test4` as a line in a file called mycmds.txt and then run `./mysript.sh < mycmds.txt` I just get an empty line in out.txt file.

So what am I doing wrong here? What is the proper way to store arguments in a file and pass them to a script so that they will be treated just as if they came from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the content of `mycmds.txt` available as command line parameters, just inline the content when you call `myscript.sh`:

```
./myscript.sh $(< mycmds.txt)
```

Comment: Ooo.. I like the looks of `$(< file)`. +1

Comment: Thanks, this seems clean and simple and works. Not sure why the $ is not mentioned more when I google "input redirection unix", but maybe its a semantics thing. Anyway thanks.

Comment: From the *bash* manual: "The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file)". It has little to do with input redirection, so don't think of it as some fancy form of the `< file`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `<` is input redirection and sends that line in as standard input to the process, nothing at all to do with command line arguments.

You can do something like:

```
./myscript.sh $(cat mycmds.txt)
```

The `$(xyz)` construct *runs* `xyz` then uses its standard output to construct that part of the command. For example:

```
ls $(expr 1 + 3)
```

will attempt to give you a directoy listing for the file called `4`, as follows.

First the command `expr 1 + 3` is executed and the output is `4`. This is then substituted in to the outer command to give you `ls 4` and that is executed.

Comment: Thanks. I choose a different but similar answer. I guess I'm sort of confused why < doesn't pass the contents of the file as if they were typed at the command line. I thought that was the point. Obviously I'm missing some subtlety here and the use of $ is required.

Answer (score 0):

The subtlety you miss is that the standard input and positional parameters are not the same thing.

Standard input, which you can redirect with the '<', or even from another program with '|' is a sequence of bytes. A script can read stdin with, well, the `read` command.

Positional parameters are numbered 1 to N and hold the value of each argument. The shell refers to them as $1 to ${42} (if you gave that many).

Standard input and positional parameters are indepent of one another. You can have both, either, or none, depending how you call a program (and what that program expects):

1. Both: `grep -E pattern < file`
2. Just stdin: `wc < file`
3. Just positional paramters: `echo Here are five positional parameters`
4. Neither: `ls`